# How to add a new cell to a TableView for each character in a string?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I am trying to take a string from a TextView and add a new row for each character in TextView.text.

so if the TextView text = "hi there" for example, I would like the Table View to look like this:

h

i

(space)

t

h

e

r

e

---

thank you!

Comment: So, you have a dynamic table view. Start with a prototype cell, probably set to "basic" configuration.  For each character, dequeue the re-usable cell and set it's value accordingly.  Also make sure that the number of rows match the length of the `String`.  The basic answer to your question is, [go read one or more tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=uitableview&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) - SO is not a replacement for due diligence and effort will be rewarded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the user enters new text convert your string into an array of characters:

```
let chars = Array(string)
```

Use the array of caracters as the data source for your table view. Call `reloadData()` on your table view after changing the character array.

Your data source methods might look like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chars.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(chars[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

### Edit:

Below is a fully implemented subclass of UITableViewController.

To use it:

1. Add the class to your project as a Swift file.
2. Add a UITableViewController scene to your storyboard
3. Select the "Identity Inspector" and change the class to
   `CharacterTableViewController`
4. Drag a container view onto the view controller that you want to
   contain your table view. (I'll call this the "parent" view
   controller)
5. Control-drag from the container view to your
   `CharacterTableViewController`. In the resulting pop-up menu, select
   "embed" to create an embed segue.
6. Add a `prepare(for:sender:)` (prepareForSegue) method to your parent
   view controller that tries to cast segue.destination to type
   `CharacterTableViewController` using an `if let` and if it succeeds, save the `CharacterTableViewController` to an instance variable. (Let's call it `characterVC`.)
7. Add a text view to your parent view controller. Control drag into your parent view controller to add an `IBOutlet` to the text view. Call the outlet `theTextView`.
8. Add a button to the parent view controller. Control-drag from the button into your parent view controller to create an IBAction. In the button action, fetch the text from `theTextView` and pass it to `characterVC` (`characterVC.contentString = theTextView.text`)

---

```
import UIKit

class CharacterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    public var contentString: String? {
        didSet {
            if let string = contentString {
                characters = Array(string)
            } else {
                characters = nil
            }
        }
    }

    var characters: [Character]? {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return characters?.count ?? 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(characters?[indexPath.row] ?? Character(""))
        return cell
    }
}
```

### Edit #2:

I created a project that uses the table view class above in a demo project. You can download it at the following link: https://github.com/DuncanMC/CharacterTableView.git

Comment: I get an error on the line 'cell.textLabel?.text = chars[indexPath.row]', It says Cannot assign value of type 'Character' to type 'String?'

Comment: So convert the Character to a String (see the edit to my answer.)

Comment: I have tried using many other examples of dynamic TableViews and still can't seem to get any data to show up in any of the cells. Any thoughts??

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I banged out a functioning subclass of UITableViewController that has a `String` property `contentString`. If you set that property it should "just work."

Comment: Sorry about me being so lost on this topic and thank you for the help, but I am still a little lost on step 6. I don't understand how I would set my TextView.text from my other controller as the string for the tableview in the CharacterTableViewController script.

Comment: The instructions I posted would let the parent view controller install a static string into the charactersTableViewController. You've got more work to do in order to feed it from a text view.

Comment: I changed step 6 and added a few more steps.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I'm not sure why this is giving you so much trouble. It's not that complicated.

Comment: I got it working thank you for all the help, sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Can you explain what was wrong with your code? It's likely to help somebody else reading this thread.

Comment: The reason the code wasn't working for me was the fact that I had the prepare(for segue: method set up wrong. I was close but It was just a small change that made it work.

Comment: You should edit your question to show the bad code, AND the fix that made it work. Others might learn something.

Answer (score 1):

This one is more directly. Hope you like it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return textView.text.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let myText = textView.text
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(myText[myText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: indexPath.row)])"
    return cell
}
```

There was a typo. I fixed it and show you the result.

[image]

Comment: It's a bad idea to use the convents of a view object as your source of data. Much better to build an array of characters from the user's input and then use that array as the data source.

Comment: This also just threw many errors that I was not able to work through.

Comment: In my comment above I meant "contents", not "convents". You should not use a view as a place to store data. When the user enters new text you should copy it out of the field into some sort of data model. See my answer for a better approach.